# Can fractals be formed using geometric figures other than straight lines

Tags: geometry, fractals

So fractals are something which fascinate me a lot. Most of the fractals I've seen till date are mostly formed by triangles or, precisely, straight lines. can fractals be formed by using something like, circles or spirals?

Comment: Do you consider the Mandelbrot and Julia sets to be composed of straight lines?

Comment: In my opinion, yes,  because ultimately when we zoom them up, they are composed of straight lines

Comment: "ultimately when we zoom them up, they are composed of straight lines" - doubtful; being able to do that "implies" (in a way that could be made more rigorous) differentiability of that perimeter.

Comment: well, I don't have much knowledge, just started studying about them ...I am sure its a long way to go

Answer (score 1):

As observed by others, fractals can be built from lots of things. A good example is the [Apollonian gasket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonian_gasket); examples with less intuitive constructions include the [Julia sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia_set), their big cousin the [Mandelbrot set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set), [Newton fractals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_fractal), and [fractal flames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal_flame), among many, many others. There's also the [Wada basin fractal](http://paulbourke.net/fractals/wada/) which isn't so geometric in nature, but its "construction" only involves spheres.

Another, somewhat sillier example is [Romanesco broccoli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanesco_broccoli), an excellent example of a natural fractal (though I'm not enough of a botanist to know whether it's somehow composed of straight lines).

Answer (score 0):

Fractals can be composed of pretty much anything. You of course have the Koch Snowflake and Hilbert Curve, which are cool, but you should look into the following:

- Sierpinski Curve and Menger Sponge, fractals from a plane and a cube
- Mandelbrot/Julia sets, fractals formed in the complex plane from recursion
- Weierstrass function, which shows fractal properties, and while it's still "a line", it's certainly interesting and strange enough to differentiate (no pun intended) itself from the other "line-made fractals"

A bunch of methods for making fractals can actually be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal#Common_techniques_for_generating_fractals), I'll bet some of those are the kinds of things you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The fractal objects in this paper by Vincent Borelli et al. are made exclusively of curves.
http://www.pnas.org/content/109/19/7218.full

In fact, the method in the paper is very general, and used to create $C^1$ isometric embeddings of surfaces in three dimensional space when the curvature of the surface to be embedded prevents it.